# Can a DVD production be burned to a CD-ROM

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

Assuming the size of a DVD-encoded program does not exceed the capacity of a CD-ROM, can the CD-ROM function as a DVD? Wouldn't DVD players have a problem reading it?

Comment: It really depends on the dvd-players.  A given product can add support for CD-ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it depends on what you mean by "DVD-encoded program".  If you are talking about data, then you should not have a problem just burning the smaller amount of data as DVD-ROM drives can read CD-ROM as well.  If you're talking about DVD video, then it won't work (at least not directly).  The CD and DVD adhere to different standards, so they can't be used interchangeably.  However, you could burn your project as a VCD (Video CD) which can be read by most modern DVD players and provides similar functionality to DVDs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, and no they won't. DVD players read CD's too, especially DVD-ROM drives.

It's important to realize that what you would have would still just be a CD-ROM. Any drive will just adjust to reading CD content. The disc will not be a DVD-ROM disc. So, just for argument's sake, if you tried to put actual DVD video content on a CD, it will not be recognized as a DVD.